# Two-way data binding is not working on text boxes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I tried to implement two-way data binding in two text boxes using AngularJS, however it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="tasksController"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="username" value="{{userage}}"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="userage" value="{{username}}">
</body>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Some code could be usefull ...

Comment: You have inverted the two variables ng-model username has value userage

Comment: Not getting your point?

Comment: <input type="text" ng-model="username" value="{{userage}}"> if you look at this line ng-model is username, but value is userage. The second line is the other way round. It may not be important, but it certainly looks wrong.

Comment: Check the Angular library. You are giving the `angular-route.js`

Comment: @vamsikrishnamannem actually I have missed that script line while posting the question ...it is on the code

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined `tasksController` in your Angular code:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('tasksController', function($scope){
        $scope.username = "John Doe";
        $scope.userage = 45;
    });
</script>
```

The model scope will then work. Also, you don't need to bind the model to the input value. `ng-model` binds the value automatically :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username">
<input type="text" ng-model="userage">
```

Comment: B, you are not getting my point...I know how can we pass the values using the $scope service from the controller to view....this is not my question.......what I want to do...when I write something on textbox 1...it will bind the value with textbox 2....I mean display the same text as I entered in textbox1 in textbox2...and when I write something on textbox2...it will display or append the entered text in textbox 1...2 way binding in textboxes....I hope now..you can understand my problem..

Comment: What is your question then, @needhelpinphp?

Comment: what I want to do...when I write something on textbox 1...it will bind the value with textbox 2....I mean display the same text as I entered in textbox1 in textbox2...and when I write something on textbox2...it will display or append the entered text in textbox 1...2 way binding in textboxes

Comment: In that case you fundamentally misunderstand the concept of two-way data binding. Its purpose is not what your are implying. [Here's an explanation of what two-way data binding means](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding). I suggest you post another question on how to display the model values of opposing inputs.

Comment: Can you explain me the how can I display the model values in opposing inputs  in the same thread

Comment: That is a question for a new thread. You will get much better answers that way.